# Is there a Rules Action to set an entity reference field to null / empty?

Tags: rules, entities

Is there any rules action you can use to set an entity reference field to null or empty?

Thanks very much and have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, got it. If anyone else runs into a problem doing this. The issue I had was that I was leaving the data selector blank and it was giving me an error message. BUT If you switch to the direct input mode and leave it blank it will work. Have a great one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Set a data value** action.  To be able to select the correct field, you may need to add a condition **Node is of type**.  (Rules does not always know about which fields should be available if you do not set a condition.)

Comment: Thanks patrick, but how do you actually assign the value as Null? I tried using Null and I get an error. I tried leaving the field blank and I get an error. What value / token do you put in the set data to field?